# Excel 2010: Average results between 25th and 75th Percentile

Tags: excel, percentile

I have managed to get a solution for an easy Average of the 25th and 75th percentile, but to average the values between them appear to be a tad problematic.

My current instruction is as follows:
    {AVERAGE(AND(F$1:F$489>PERCENTILE(F$1:F$489,0.25),F$1:F$489<
        PERCENTILE(F$1:F$489,0.75),F$1:F$489))}

I am trying to average all values in Column F where they reside between percentile 25 and 75.

Thanks!

Comment: try this one: `=AVERAGEIFS(F$1:F$489, F$1:F$489, ">" & PERCENTILE(F$1:F$489,0.25), F$1:F$489, "<" & PERCENTILE(F$1:F$489,0.75))`

Comment: I agree that `AVERAGEIFS` is the way to go but FWIW if you use an array formula with `AVERAGE` you can't use `AND` because `AND` returns a single result not an array as required - valid syntax would be: `=AVERAGE(IF((F$1:F$489>PERCENTILE(F$1:F$489,0.25))*(F$1:F$489< PERCENTILE(F$1:F$489,0.75)),F$1:F$489))` - array entered

Comment: Thanks @barryhoudini I will definitely try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In excel it helps to slip your formula into separate chunks. So in one column you print which percentile the values are in. Then you use that as input for the next. That way you can see what the intermediate values are.

For this you could actually use AVERAGEIF. This average you can give a condition that the percentile should be between 25 and 75.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, perhaps it is safer!